# Json To Features ERROR 001558: Error parsing json file. The workspace is not connected

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geojson, convert, json, error-001558

I am trying to convert a `JSON` file into a feature. My code was working fine until today and now I am getting the following error - `ExecuteError: ERROR 001558: Error parsing json file '<filepath>'. The workspace is not connected.`.

I tried it manually in `ArcMap` using this proceedure:

- I first checked that the JSON file looked correct (had all the prerequisites like geometryType, Features, etc...).
- In arcMap (10.5), I went to toolbox > Conversion Tools > JSON > JSON To Features.
- I input the filepath to the .json file and then made sure the output went to a .gdb.
- I double checked the filepaths.

Same results: ERROR 001558. I even tried the default output, which went to the ArcGIS\Default.gdb. I also got the same error:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 001558: Error parsing json file ''. The
>   workspace is not connected. Failed to execute (JSONToFeatures).

In researching this issue, I found the ArcGIS Pro page on [001558: Error parsing .json file `<value>`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01551-01575-001558.htm) which states that the `The JSON must have at least the geometryType, spatialReference, fields, and features (with geometry and attributes) property.` I checked the data and it has 
`geometryType`, `spatialReference`, `fields`, and `features` which have  `attributes` and `geometry`.

```
{"displayFieldName": "CSLF_ID",
"fieldAliases": {...},
"geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
"spatialReference": {
  "wkid": 102100,
  "latestWkid": 3857
},
"fields": [...],
"features": [
  {"attributes": {...},
   "geometry": {...}
  },...]}
```

So, I am wondering if there might be something else causing the error. Or can anyone see an issue with the JSON file above?

Comment: What are the detailed steps that you are using when you are "trying it manually in arcMap"?

Comment: I first checked that the JSON file looked correct (had all the prerequisites like geometryType, Features, etc...). In arcMap (10.5), I went to toolbox > Conversion Tools > JSON > JSON To Features. I input the filepath to the .json file and then made sure the output went to a .gdb. I double checked the filepaths. Same results: ERROR 001558. I even tried the default output, which went to the ArcGIS\Default.gdb.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Not all potential answerers will read all comments.  It is your question that they are most likely to focus their volunteered time on.

Comment: Added the manual steps I took to the question.

Comment: It's odd that the only documentation for that error number seems to be in ArcGIS Pro when you are seeing it from ArcMap.

Comment: It is weird; especially since it popped up in ArcMap.

Comment: The fact you see an error topic in Pro vs. ArcMap shouldn't mean anything. Its very likely when the topic was written it was not included in the arcmap help due to a simple oversight if the actual error code happens in both software products.

Comment: can you copy/paste the json into jsonlint.com and confirm its valid?

Comment: As far as cutting and pasting the json into jsonlint.com...I tried (it's 4,880,000+ lines long), but its too large and kept crashing. However, the data itself is taken from a request to a REST WMS layer and formatted using the Python json module. If you know of large data validators (can you validate json in Notepad ++ or another IDE??), let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a bit late, but I had the same problem.

**How the problem raised:**

I was downloading my data as GeoJSON for different areas with multiple requests. To import all the data at once in ArcGIS Pro my downloader-script combined all entries under "features". Some features were downloaded by multiple requests so by adding all into one array caused some features to have been added twice.

**The solution:**

Make sure that all features you have in that array have **unique OBJECTID**s (feature→attributes→OBJECTID).

In my case I checked for every feature if one with the same OBJECTID already exists in the final GeoJSON before adding it.